# Subtract circles to be transparent?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a problem.
I am trying to create a shape with CSS3, that have to be transparent around it.

I there anyway to subtract a div from a div, leaving the empty space transparent?

I have created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/juxiwani/1/edit) to show my problem.
I need to make the **green** boxes transparent, so the shape stands out for it self.

```css
body html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#beerglass {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.beertop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.beerbody {
  height: 97%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1%;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6%;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 1%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6%;
  border-top-right-radius: -1%;
  border-radius: -100%;
  margin: 3% 0%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.beerbottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
  height: 4%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0% 7.5%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.beercircle-l {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 60%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0% -10%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.beercircle-r {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0% 80%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="beerglass">
  <div class="beertop"></div>
  <div class="beerbody"></div>
  <div class="beerbottom"></div>
  <!--<div class="beercircle-l"></div>-->
  <!--<div class="beercircle-r"></div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: By transparent, do you mean none of the shape should show or it should just be the border/outline?  Or semi-transparent?

Comment: like this: http://jsbin.com/juxiwani/4/edit ?

Comment: The green shapes should not be shown, but when they are removed they should leave a transparent space.
But think i might have found a solution in radial-gradient

Comment: You want the outcome to be similar to @aldanux, you just don't want to achieve it by setting a default background color, correct?

Comment: @aldanux nope, like they sould be all gone. The shape have to go on a gradient background that changes with responsive. So they have to be all gone

Comment: I make it only this way to understand correctly what you want to achieve...

Comment: Is there a reason why you could not use `svg` for this?

Comment: @t.niese In the end it will become a beerglas, that gets more and more filled by a number of "entries" in my database. Don't know if i can create a .svg to contain the beer animation that has to go up and have waves at the top

Comment: I think using `svg` or `canvas` is the best way to solve this (if you don't need to support older browsers). You can manipulate the `svg` and/or use it as mask for image. Alternatively there is also [`clip-path`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-animation-of-clip-path) (that is not limited to images) but I think there is a better browser support with using `svg`

Comment: Maybe you can use `clip:rect()`. See this [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)